# Idris not reducing map lookup

Tags: idris

Why does is not reduce the function call? How can I verify at compile time that a map contains a key value pair?

```
import Data.SortedMap

N : SortedMap String Type
N = fromList
    [ ("a", Nat)
    , ("b", String)
    ]

t : lookup "a" N = Just Nat
t = Refl

Type mismatch between
        Just Nat = Just Nat (Type of Refl)
and
        lookup "a" (fromList [("a", Nat), ("b", String)]) = Just Nat (Expected type)

Specifically:
        Type mismatch between
                Just Nat
        and
                lookup "a" (fromList [("a", Nat), ("b", String)])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must have something todo with the implementation of `SortedMap` as the version using a plain `List` works as expected:

```
N : List (String, Type)
N =
    [ ("a", Nat)
    , ("b", String)
    ]

t : lookup "a" N = Just Nat
t = Refl
```

According to the docs `Data.SortedMap.lookup` is total as well, so it should reduce. Maybe the reason is that the functions and data types in `SortedMap` seem to have the export qualifier, whereas the ones in Data.List use `public export`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! :)
I have spent over an hour trying to figure out why one of my proofs wasn't compiling and started to question my understanding of things before I have found the proper keywords to google in order to find this and solve the whole thing by using `public export`...